# Imagery Providers avaiable in cesium

Tags: arcgis, cesiumjs

I'm using the following imagery provider for streetView:

```
new Cesium.ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider({
    url: 'http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer'
})
```

But it takes more time to load the layer. Whenever I'm loading the 3d model it is taking more time to load the entire layer. Is there any other streetview layer which is more efficient?

Comment: What 3D model are you referring to?

Comment: 3D model refering to .gltf file. i'm converting .dae to .gltf